# Prevent UISegmentedControl change

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How can I prevent segmented control change without set it to be disabled.
Basically I need something like shouldChangeSegment.
There is a case when I need to show alert message and prevent segment change.

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Yes. I added selector for UIControlEvents.ValueChanged and when segment changes I show alert and change segmnetedControl.selectedSegmentIndex to previus value.

Answer (score 0):

setting `disabled = true` is the normal way. There is no `shouldChangeSegment` type delegate method.

You should also be able to set `userInteractionEnabled = false`.

What's wrong with using `disabled = true`?

Comment: in that case how can I handle disabled segment touch and show alert why that segment is disabled?

Comment: You can't disable individual segments.